# Postgres 9.x Joining on Overlaping Date & Time Range

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have several tables that have a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column along with some additional information. I need to be able to join these tables such that all of the information on each row is "valid" as of a given date and time window (labeled `begin` and `end` in the desired result set).

### My current approach:

**Option #1**

1. Create a unique list of times.
2. Convert each point in time into a window of time for the unique list (the "valid" window of time) and for each original table. [`LEAD(...) OVER (...)`]
3. Join the original tables to the unique list of times.

**Option #2**

1. Convert each point in time (`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`) into a window of time for each table. [`LEAD(...) OVER (...)`]
2. Join the tables where windows overlap.
3. Return `GREATEST(foo.start, bar.start)` & `LEAST(foo.stop, bar.stop)` from each window to find true "valid" window.

### For example:

**Table: foo**

```
  fooid  |  description  |       datetime
---------|---------------|-----------------------
    1    |   Varsion 1   |  2010-01-01 00:00:00  
    2    |   Varsion 2   |  2010-07-01 00:00:00
```

**Table: bar**

```
  barid  |  fooid  |  description  |       datetime
---------|---------|---------------|-----------------------
    1    |    1    |   Varsion A   |  2010-01-01 00:00:00
    2    |    1    |   Varsion B   |  2010-02-01 00:00:00
    3    |    1    |   Varsion C   |  2010-03-01 00:00:00
    4    |    1    |   Varsion D   |  2010-04-01 00:00:00
    5    |    1    |   Varsion E   |  2010-05-01 00:00:00
    6    |    1    |   Varsion F   |  2010-06-01 00:00:00
    7    |    2    |   Varsion A   |  2010-07-01 00:00:00
    8    |    2    |   Varsion B   |  2010-08-01 00:00:00
    9    |    2    |   Varsion C   |  2010-09-01 00:00:00
    10   |    2    |   Varsion D   |  2010-10-01 00:00:00
    11   |    2    |   Varsion E   |  2010-11-01 00:00:00
    12   |    2    |   Varsion F   |  2010-12-01 00:00:00
```

**Simplified Desired Results**

```
        begin          |          end          |  fooid  |   foo_desc    |       foostart        |        foostop        |  barid  |   bar_desc   |       foostart        |        foostop        
-----------------------|-----------------------|---------|---------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|---------|--------------|-----------------------|-----------------------
         ...           |         ...           |   ...   |      ...      |         ...           |         ...           |   ...   |     ...      |         ...           |         ...           
  2010-05-01 00:00:00  |  2010-06-01 00:00:00  |    1    |   Varsion 1   |  2010-01-01 00:00:00  |  2010-07-01 00:00:00  |    5    |  Varsion E   |  2010-05-01 00:00:00  |  2010-06-01 00:00:00
  2010-06-01 00:00:00  |  2010-07-01 00:00:00  |    1    |   Varsion 1   |  2010-01-01 00:00:00  |  2010-07-01 00:00:00  |    6    |  Varsion F   |  2010-06-01 00:00:00  |        infinity
  2010-07-01 00:00:00  |  2010-08-01 00:00:00  |    2    |   Varsion 2   |  2010-07-01 00:00:00  |       infinity        |    7    |  Varsion A   |  2010-07-01 00:00:00  |  2010-08-01 00:00:00
  2010-08-01 00:00:00  |  2010-09-01 00:00:00  |    2    |   Varsion 2   |  2010-07-01 00:00:00  |       infinity        |    8    |  Varsion B   |  2010-08-01 00:00:00  |  2010-09-01 00:00:00
         ...           |         ...           |   ...   |      ...      |         ...           |         ...           |   ...   |     ...      |         ...           |         ...
```

---

### My Question:

What is the best way to achieve this? I have created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/57254/5) showing two different solutions, and I would like to hear ideas on each as well as possible solutions not in the fiddle.

### Update #1:

In the example, there are only two tables that need to be joined... however, in some cases I may need to join several tables 3, 4, or more.

### Update #2:

With **Option #1**, my problem is that when I have large result sets I find that the initial sub query can be large and postgres can't use an index. This causes a large performance hit. On the other hand, I find it to be the most accurate as I can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` against it and get pertinent `NULL` data back.

With **Option #2**, the query planner is able to use the indexes on the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` columns; however, joining more then two tables becomes more complex in the `FROM` clause. I can move the `(table1.start, table1.stop) OVERLAPS (table2.start, table2.stop)` into the `WHERE` clause but then I loose the pertinent `NULL` data.

All of this makes me wonder if there is a better way...

Comment: Clue you rephrase this a bit? Because there are no barid 5,6,7,8 anywhere in your example data. Also, these are audit tables with a valid_until datetime, right?

Comment: @Denis - Sorry, I left the ID's off... I have updated the question. Also this is more of a log (rather then an audit table). Each record is valid as of its creation timestamp and remains valid until it is overridden by the next record.

Comment: The fooid is a primary key for foo. It points to the '2010-01-01' date. Now, where does the foostop date '2010-07-01' originate from ? is there some built-in 6month requirement, or is ist inherited from the unrelated (IMHO) fooid=2 record ? Also: why is there a fooid (FK) column in the bar-table?  Please clarify.

Comment: @joop - Yes, fooid is the PK for table foo. fooid 2 is also the end point of fooid 1 (this is the same configuration of the bar table... the next value is the end of the current time window. Also, the bar table references the foo table with fooid... but there is no guarantee that the timestamps will be consistent between tables... so the real focus is on joining the overlapping times.

Comment: So, in fact both the fooid and barid are surrogate keys, and all the matching you want to perform should be based on the timestamps? (this is illustrated by Erwin's answer, where {fooid,barid} are completely omitted from the join)

Comment: @wildplasser - you are correct, I could have further simplified the question by removing the keys... they are in fact necessary in my real use case; however, I'm more focused on the best way to join the two tables. See "Update #2" above for some more info...

Comment: The update does not add much, IMHO. Better remove the unneeded columns and add the actual tabledefinitions+keys instead. BTW: The actual size of the tables is irrelevant if you prefer correctness to efficiency. (the timestamp columns look like almost candidate-keys to me, anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default value for the window functions [`lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) and `lag()` instead of `coalesce()`:

```
lead(datetime, 1, 'infinity') OVER (ORDER BY fooid, datetime) AS stop
```

... instead of:

```
COALESCE(LEAD(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY fooid, datetime), 'infinity'::TIMESTAMP) AS stop
```

With `PARTITION BY fooid` it's pointless to (redundantly) `ORDER BY fooid`.

```
PARTITION BY fooid ORDER BY datetime
```

... instead of:

```
(PARTITION BY fooid ORDER BY fooid, datetime)
```

All the added double-quotes are just noise for *legal* identifiers.  Makes the query hard too read.

Comment: Thanks @erwin... all of those are good points. I'm not familiar with codereview, I'll check it out. I have seen your comments on SO all over, thanks for being such a strong contributor. Do you have an opinion on the two techniques that I'm currently using?

Comment: Other than that: your question is too broad for Stackoverflow. Consider: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question in it's current form is not acceptable on code review. `fooid` and `barid` means it isn't concrete code which is require on code review. The SQL for the table definitions is missing. There are other problems as well.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: Of course, it would need to be improved. Anyway, this is an old question, I just split that hint from the answer, where it didn't belong. Might as well delete that ...